# Make d3.js / NVD3 Charts Keyboard Accessible

Tags: javascript, d3.js, accessibility, data-visualization, section508

I am using [an interactive D3.js chart from the NVD3 library](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html) which has data labels that appear when you mouse over the chart. For accessibility purposes, I would like to make these same labels display when only using the keyboard arrow keys. Is there a good way to accomplish this?